# BuddyPress 1.7: How do I display username under avatar in activity feed?

Tags: android-activity, buddypress

In the BuddyPress 1.7 activity feed (mytheme/buddypress/activity/entry.php), the user's avatar gets displayed beside their status update like so:

```
    <div class="activity-avatar">
      <a href="<?php bp_activity_user_link(); ?>">
        <?php bp_activity_avatar(); ?>
      </a>
    </div>
```

I'd like to display the user's username underneath their avatar, and I tried using this code, but for some reason she no work.

```
    <div class="activity-avatar">
      <a href="<?php bp_activity_user_link(); ?>">
        <?php bp_activity_avatar(); ?>
      </a>
      <br />
      <a href="<?php bp_activity_user_link(); ?>" class="nicename">
        @<?php bp_get_displayed_user_username(); ?>
      </a>
    </div>
```

Can someone please kindly show me how to simply display the user's username/nicename in the activity feed entry?

Comment: http://buddypress.org/support/topic/bp-1-7-how-do-i-display-username-under-avatar-in-activity-feed/

Answer (score 2):

```
bp_get_displayed_user_username()
```

This function can't display anything, as you are not on user profile page.

User this function:

```
bp_get_activity_user_id()
```

And then display userdata that you want with `bp_core_get_core_userdata()` for example. Like this:

```
print_r( bp_core_get_core_userdata( bp_get_activity_user_id() ) );
```